# Iterating over latest git tags

Tags: bash, git, github, gitlab

I would like to iterate over latest versions of git tags, that means crawling through their content. I am looking for solution that will:
from list of example tags:

```
A@1.0.0
A@1.1.0
A@2.1.0
B@1.0.0
B@1.0.1
C@1.0.0
```

will choose `A@2.1.0` `B@1.0.1` `C@1.0.0` and iterate through their content to let me grep for one regex. Just like I would checkout each and use grep from the level of project. I've tried using this:

```
git ls-remote --tags
```

but it lists all tags and doesn't open their content.

Comment: what do you mean by `doesnt open their content` ?

Comment: I mean that I don't get into project root inside it. The main folder with the project's version

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution for this is to write a little script (bash, powershell, python, ...):

1. Get list of all git tags by `git tag`
2. Checkout 1. tag
3. Do what you want to do
4. Checkout 2. tag
5. Do what you want to do
6. ...

Maybe as an alternativ, you can take a look at the option of `git log`. With `git log --all -S <text>` you are able to search for  in the whole history. (Use `git log --all -G <text>` for RegEx search)